# String id does not change when string changes in Python. Complexity of adding char to string

Tags: python, string, optimization, time-complexity, immutability

I thought that Python string's id must change each time after changing string. But I found that the real behaviour is different. For example, not all strings of code below output are different:

```py
In [1]: s = 'a' 
   ...: for i in range(20): 
   ...:     print(id(s)) 
   ...:     s += 'a' 

Out[1]: 139687167358256
   ...: 139687049975984
   ...: 139687049975984
   ...: 139687049975984
   ...: 139687049975984
   ...: 139687049975984
   ...: 139687049975984
   ...: 139687049975984
   ...: 139687049975984
   ...: 139687049975984
   ...: 139687049975984
   ...: 139687049975984
   ...: 139687049975984
   ...: 139687049975984
   ...: 139687049975984
   ...: 139687066878640
   ...: 139687066878640
   ...: 139687066878640
   ...: 139687066878640
   ...: 139687066878640
```

That's why I decided that Python kernel is trying to optimize code and starting strange manipulations with strings in memory. Another argument for this assumption is the fact that constant-ids are going with segments which size is powers of 2:

```py
In [2]: s = 'a' 
   ...: prev = id(s) 
   ...: count = 1 
   ...: for i in range(150): 
   ...:     s += 'a' 
   ...:     cur = id(s) 
   ...:     if cur != prev: 
   ...:         print(len(s), count) 
   ...:         count = 1 
   ...:     else: 
   ...:         count += 1 
   ...:     prev = cur 

Out[2]: 2 1
   ...: 16 14
   ...: 32 16
   ...: 48 16
   ...: 64 16
   ...: 80 16
   ...: 96 16
   ...: 112 16
   ...: 128 16
   ...: 144 16
```

But there is another strange thing in all this. Let's look what will happen with segments sizes with increase of string size:

```py
In [3]: s = 'a' 
   ...: prev = id(s) 
   ...: count = 1 
   ...: for i in range(10 ** 9): 
   ...:     s += 'a' 
   ...:     cur = id(s) 
   ...:     if cur != prev: 
   ...:         print(len(s), count) 
   ...:         count = 1 
   ...:     else: 
   ...:         count += 1 
   ...:     prev = cur 

Out[3]:
   ...: 2 1
   ...: 16 14
   ...: 32 16
   ...: 48 16
   ...: 64 16
   ...: 80 16
   ...: 96 16
   <...>
   ...: 448 16
   ...: 464 16
   ...: 472 8
   ...: 504 32
   ...: 536 32
   ...: 568 32
   ...: 600 32
   ...: 648 48
   ...: 1048 400
   ...: 1272 224
   ...: 1336 64
   ...: 1416 80
   ...: 1512 96
   ...: 1544 32
   ...: 1832 288
   ...: 1864 32
   ...: 1880 16
   ...: 1992 112
   ...: 2040 48
   ...: 2104 64
   ...: 2152 48
   ...: 2216 64
   ...: 39512 37296
   ...: 752776 713264
   ...: 753592 816
   ...: 1511352 757760
   ...: 3026872 1515520
   ...: 6057912 3031040
   ...: 6062008 4096
   ...: 6066104 4096
   ...: 6070200 4096
   <...>
   ...: 8396728 4096
   ...: 16797624 8400896
   ...: 16801720 4096
   <...>
   ...: 33537976 4096
   ...: 33542072 4096
   ...: 67088312 33546240
   ...: 67092408 4096
   ...: 67096504 4096
   ...: 67100600 4096
   ...: 67104696 4096
   ...: 67108792 4096
   ...: 67112888 4096
   ...: 134229944 67117056
   ...: 268464056 134234112
   ...: 536932280 268468224
```

Finally, we can try to approximate the complexity of adding char to end of string. Yet again, I thought, that complexity of adding n chars to string in a loop is O(n^2). But my experiments shows that it is O(n):

```py
In [4]: def foo(n): 
   ...:     c = time() 
   ...:     s = 'a' 
   ...:     for i in range(n): 
   ...:         s += 'a' 
   ...:     return time() - c 

In [5]: foo(10 ** 6) / foo(10 ** 3)                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[5]: 1124.5325443786983
```

I can't explain this behaviour especially when string become enough long.
So can anybody help me with this? Desirable in detail, please, if it is possible.

UPD:

1. It seems like this does not happens with tuples. Their ids changes on every loop iteration.
2. Replacing string literal 'a' with variable with value 'a' does not change behaviour with constant-ids. So does not replacing `s += 'a'` with `s = s + 'a'`. **But!** Replacing `s = s + 'a'` with `s = 'a' + s` leads to changing id on every loop iteration.
3. After replacing 'a' literal with variable called `a` I supposed that adding function call into loop body may change the situation (because function may  have a side-effect on `a` variable). So I tried to call "formal" function (that did not anything) between `a` declaration and `s = s + a` line. And it does not made a difference. Finally, I tried to add non-constant length line to `s`, but random length:

```py
In [4]: s = 'a' 
   ...: prev = id(s) 
   ...: count = 1 
   ...: for i in range(10 ** 8): 
   ...:     s = s + 'a' * randint(1, 100) 
   ...:     cur = id(s) 
   ...:     if cur == prev: 
   ...:         count += 1 
   ...:     else: 
   ...:         print(len(s), count) 
   ...:         count = 1 
   ...:     prev = cur 


Out[4]:
   ...: 37 1
   ...: 76 1
   ...: 154 1
   ...: 187 1
   ...: 268 1
   ...: 288 1
   ...: 305 1
   ...: 344 2
   ...: 380 1
   ...: 438 1
   ...: 527 1
   ...: 612 2
   ...: 639 1
   ...: 817 2
   ...: 888 2
   ...: 984 3
   ...: 1077 2
   ...: 1166 2
   ...: 1267 2
   ...: 1378 2
   ...: 1641 5
   ...: 1777 2
   ...: 2164 9
   ...: 2509 5
   ...: 2750 6
   ...: 3394 14
   ...: 3674 5
   ...: 4030 5
   ...: 4077 3
   ...: 4569 10
   ...: 4868 5
   ...: 5700 14
   ...: 6840 23
   ...: 8278 25
   ...: 136672 2541
   ...: 19397763 381558
   ...: 19398587 18
   ...: 19402713 84
   ...: 19406810 81
   ...: 19410889 81
   ...: 19415002 82
   ...: 19419075 83
   ...: 19423225 80
   ...: 19427293 70
   ...: 19431357 88
   <And so on...>
```

4. If we'll use `s += 'a'` but with calling hash function from `s` after that ids will change on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use Python 3, **this behavior is not specified by the Python language**.

Actually, [the Python 3 standard states](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str):

> **Strings are immutable** sequences of Unicode code points.
>   [...]
>   There is also no mutable string type, but **str.join()** or io.StringIO **can be used to efficiently construct strings from multiple fragments**.

Mutability must be respected from the user point of view. However, the interpreter can make some tricks to reuse the object internally if this does not introduce side effects regarding the Python standard.

Regarding `id`, [the Python standard states](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=id#id):

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is guaranteed to be **unique and constant** for this object during its **lifetime**. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.
>
> **CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object in memory**.

So, here is the trick: results from the `id` call for one iteration may or may not be equal to the one of the previous iteration. This is **undefined** because the object referenced by `s` is a different from the one referenced in the previous iteration (since the previous string is no longer referenced, it can be freed and its lifetime ended).

The CPython interpreter internally recycle the string object in memory to be faster (mainly to avoid allocations). The **resulting side effect** is a possibly better complexity. However, alternative Python implementations may not perform this trick. For example, [PyPy do not](https://www.pypy.org/performance.html#string-concatenation-is-expensive).

Thus, please use `str.join()` or `io.StringIO` for fast concatenation (as the Python standard states) and do not rely on undefined behavior or CPython implementation details as **this behavior may change in the future versions of the interpreter**.