# Python List is adding my first item twice

Tags: python

I've been trying to debug this problem most of this afternoon and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I have a yaml file read into a list of strings and I am trying to load up that data into some custom objects.

```
from typing import Any, List
import yaml

class Bar:
    def __init__(self, yml_node:Any):
        self.name = yml_node["name"]
        self.obj_type = yml_node["obj_type"]
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{{ "name": "{self.name}", "type": "{self.obj_type}" }}'
class Baz:
    def __init__(self, yml_node:Any):
        self.name = yml_node["name"]
        self.obj_type = yml_node["obj_type"]
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{{ "name": "{self.name}", "type": "{self.obj_type}" }}'

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, yml_node:Any):
        self.bars:List[Bar] = []
        self.bazs:List[Baz] = []

        print(f"self1 = {self}")
        for b in yml_node["bars"]:
            print(f"Adding {b}")
            new_bar_obj = Bar(b)
            print(f"new_bar_obj =  {new_bar_obj}")
            self.bars.extend([new_bar_obj])
            print(f"self(in for) = {self}")

        print(f"self2 = {self}")
        for b in yml_node["bazs"]:
            print(f"Adding topic {b}")
            new_baz_obj = Baz(b)
            print(f"new_baz_obj =  {new_baz_obj}")
            self.bazs.extend([new_baz_obj])
        print(f"self3 = {self}")

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{{ "bars": {stringify_list(self.bars)}, "bazs": {stringify_list(self.bazs)} }}'

def stringify_list(l:List[Any]) -> str:
    first = True

    rtn_str = "[\n"
    for i in l:
        if(first):
            rtn_str += f"{i}"
            first = False
        rtn_str += f", {i}"

    rtn_str += "]\n"
    return rtn_str

def get_obj(file_content:List[str], obj_name:str) -> Foo:
    yml_file = yaml.safe_load("".join(file_content))

    print(f"Yaml Object: {yml_file[obj_name]}")
    rtn = Foo(yml_file[obj_name])
    print(f"Returning Object: {rtn}")
    return rtn

yml_file_string = """
---
foo1:
    bars:
        - name: foo1_bar_1
          obj_type: bar
        - name: foo1_bar_2
          obj_type: bar
    bazs:
        - name: foo1_baz_1
          obj_type: baz
        - name: foo1_baz_2
          obj_type: baz
"""

yml_file_lines = yml_file_string.splitlines(True)

foo1_obj = get_obj(yml_file_lines, "foo1")
print(f"foo1_obj = {foo1_obj}")
```

I expect this to work by loading the yaml file lines into a `yaml_file` object, then passing in `yaml_file["foo1"]` part into the Foo constructor. That all happens in the `get_obj()` function.

I expect the constructor to return `foo1_obj` which will contain two lists (`bars` and `bazs`) which will each contain two `Bar` or `Baz` objects. What I am getting instead is 3 `Bar` or `Baz` objects in each list. The first item in each list is repeated 1 time. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the output I get instead:

```
Yaml Object: {'bars': [{'name': 'foo1_bar_1', 'obj_type': 'bar'}, {'name': 'foo1_bar_2', 'obj_type': 'bar'}], 'bazs': [{'name': 'foo1_baz_1', 'obj_type': 'baz'}, {'name': 'foo1_baz_2', 'obj_type': 'baz'}]}
self1 = { "bars": [
]
, "bazs": [
]
 }
Adding {'name': 'foo1_bar_1', 'obj_type': 'bar'}
new_bar_obj =  { "name": "foo1_bar_1", "type": "bar" }
self(in for) = { "bars": [
{ "name": "foo1_bar_1", "type": "bar" }, { "name": "foo1_bar_1", "type": "bar" }]
, "bazs": [
]
 }
Adding {'name': 'foo1_bar_2', 'obj_type': 'bar'}
new_bar_obj =  { "name": "foo1_bar_2", "type": "bar" }
self(in for) = { "bars": [
{ "name": "foo1_bar_1", "type": "bar" }, { "name": "foo1_bar_1", "type": "bar" }, { "name": "foo1_bar_2", "type": "bar" }]
, "bazs": [
]
 }
self2 = { "bars": [
{ "name": "foo1_bar_1", "type": "bar" }, { "name": "foo1_bar_1", "type": "bar" }, { "name": "foo1_bar_2", "type": "bar" }]
, "bazs": [
]
 }
Adding topic {'name': 'foo1_baz_1', 'obj_type': 'baz'}
new_baz_obj =  { "name": "foo1_baz_1", "type": "baz" }
Adding topic {'name': 'foo1_baz_2', 'obj_type': 'baz'}
new_baz_obj =  { "name": "foo1_baz_2", "type": "baz" }
self3 = { "bars": [
{ "name": "foo1_bar_1", "type": "bar" }, { "name": "foo1_bar_1", "type": "bar" }, { "name": "foo1_bar_2", "type": "bar" }]
, "bazs": [
{ "name": "foo1_baz_1", "type": "baz" }, { "name": "foo1_baz_1", "type": "baz" }, { "name": "foo1_baz_2", "type": "baz" }]
 }
Returning Object: { "bars": [
{ "name": "foo1_bar_1", "type": "bar" }, { "name": "foo1_bar_1", "type": "bar" }, { "name": "foo1_bar_2", "type": "bar" }]
, "bazs": [
{ "name": "foo1_baz_1", "type": "baz" }, { "name": "foo1_baz_1", "type": "baz" }, { "name": "foo1_baz_2", "type": "baz" }]
 }
foo1_obj = { "bars": [
{ "name": "foo1_bar_1", "type": "bar" }, { "name": "foo1_bar_1", "type": "bar" }, { "name": "foo1_bar_2", "type": "bar" }]
, "bazs": [
{ "name": "foo1_baz_1", "type": "baz" }, { "name": "foo1_baz_1", "type": "baz" }, { "name": "foo1_baz_2", "type": "baz" }]
 }
```

Try the code here (most of the print()'s in the code were me trying to figure out where the extra object was getting added to the lists):
https://trinket.io/python3/877a72fe9b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've only got one copy in each, but your `stringify_list` function is broken; this code:

```
for i in l:
    if(first):
        rtn_str += f"{i}"
        first = False
    rtn_str += f", {i}"
```

adds `i` (without a prefix) on the first loop, and also *unconditionally* adds it *with* a `,`  prefix on *every* loop. Thus, the first item ends up added twice.

Change it to:

```
for i in l:
    if first:
        rtn_str += f"{i}"
        first = False
    else:
        rtn_str += f", {i}"
```

and the problem will go away. That said, manually implementing such a function is kind of silly; I might suggest looking at the `pprint` module if you want custom formatted `list` output, rather than reimplementing it from scratch like this.

Note that there are much easier and more efficient ways to do this even if `pprint` isn't an option, if nothing else, the loop could be removed in favor of:

```
rtn_str += ', '.join(map(str, l))
```

which efficiently converts them all to strings and joins them all together in a bulk operation that costs `O(n)` rather than the `O(n²)` work that repeated string concatenation costs (even if CPython optimizes it a bit, it's not wise to rely on it, [it's a very brittle optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72568770/364696)).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in this function:

```
def stringify_list(l:List[Any]) -> str:
    first = True

    rtn_str = "[\n"
    for i in l:
        if(first):
            rtn_str += f"{i}"
            first = False
        rtn_str += f", {i}"

    rtn_str += "]\n"
    return rtn_str
```

As you can see, you unconditionally add the `, {i}` part of your string, regardless of it being the first item or not. Simply putting the "non first" concatenation in an `else` clause would fix it:

```
    for i in l:
        if(first):
            rtn_str += f"{i}"
            first = False
        else:
             rtn_str += f", {i}"
```

However, although the use of the `first` state variable is somewhat ingenuous, if a bit incorrect in your case, Python is a language that often frees one from these basic tasks. In this case, the simpler way of doing it is by using the `.join` method of strings: it automatically formats separator-embedded items in a nice way, with no extra logic needed to exclude the separator before the first item. Join combined with an f-string means your function can be simply stated as:

```
def stringify_list(l:List[Any]) -> str:
    return f"[\n{', '.join(str(i) for i in l)}]\n"
```